# php: mysqli login script failing for unknown reason

Tags: php, mysqli, md5

So I have my log in script that I am trying to get to work, but when I try to log in it always says no even if the test I included below says expected:(password hash here) found: (same password hash here) I have changed the code so many times in attempts to fix it, and done a load of Google searches(for those who want to give me lmgtfy links) trying to fix it. I've included as much of the code as I can without having to add fake details so stack overflow would let me add more code:

Actual script:

```
else{
    $login = login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That username/password is incorrect';
    } else {
        echo "ok";
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: index2.php');
        exit();
    }
}
print_r($errors);
//echo "expected to see: ". $pass. " "; //this was a test
//echo "found: ".$passen;               //this was too
```

Login function:

```
function login($username, $password){
$user_id = sanitize($username);

$db = get_my_db();
$username = sanitize($username);
$password = md5($password);

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND          `password` = '$password'";

return ($db->query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` =   '$username' AND `password` = '$password'") === 1) ? $user_id : false; }
```

And the `sanitize()` function is just `mysqli_real_escape_string($data)` if you want anything else, let me know, and i'll put it in. By the way, the tests script was this: and the expected function just turned the $password into an md5.

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc(); 
$pass = $row['password'];
$passen = expected($password);
```

Comment: Some possibly unrelated advices: 1. Use prepared statements! Look up MySQLi prepared statements or PDO. 2. Do **not** use MD5 for passwords anymore! Use bcrypt or scrypt in combination with a per-user salt! It's best to use PHP's built-in functions: [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash), [password_verify()](http://php.net/password_verify). A compatibility library exists for PHP < 5.50: [ircmaxell/password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: How is `sanitize` defined?

Comment: are you sure is not skipping the else statement, going inside the if ?

Comment: would SHA1 work better?

Comment: @gumbo sorry it was at the bottom, it just does mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @AndreiAndrei yes i cut off the code before it because it's confirmed to work.

Comment: @joeybab3 No, it isn't. SHA-1 is too fast. A password hash algorithm needs to be slow. There exists a good reading on Security.SE: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Comment: ok thanks for staying with me :)

Comment: do you start the session ? session_start();

Comment: what about a sha256(md5($pass))

Comment: yes andrei I start it

Comment: try echo the result of the query "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` =   '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"

Comment: When I try that, it wants it to be a string so I convert it, but it echo's nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where it fails, but a few tips:

- use salted `sha1` passwords
- do not create functions like sanitize(),get_my_db(), those dont even speedup your work
- `mysqli_` should be called with `$con` first parameter, like `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $var);`
- to get working global `$con` in local function, write `function
  login() { global $con; }`

Comment: One shouldn't use SHA-1 either. See my comment above. Global variables are in most of the cases bad design. I recommend creating a DB class.

Comment: This is my attempt to "mysqlize" phpacademy's login and register system.